# Matching an i32 value with character constants

Tags: rust

I'm writing a parser in Rust, which needs at various points to match the current token against candidate values. Some of the candidate values are characters, others are integer constants, so the token is declared as `i32`, which would be plenty to accommodate both. (All the characters to be matched against are ASCII.)

The problem is that when I supply a character constant like '(' to be matched against, the compiler complains that it expected `i32` and is getting `char`.

I tried writing e.g. `'(' as i32` but an `as` expression is not allowed as a match candidate.

Obviously I could look up the ASCII values and provide them as numbers, but it seems there should be a more readable solution. Declaring the token as `char` doesn't really seem correct, as it sometimes needs to hold integers that are not actually characters.

What's the recommended way to solve this problem?

Comment: What do the integer constants represent?

Comment: @Ry- Tokens that are not single characters. For example, tokens like `==` that are two characters, and also indicators that the current token is a string, number or whatever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- It’s a bit verbose, but your match arms could be of the form `c if c == i32::from(b'(')`.
- Another alternative would be to match on `u8::try_from(some_i32)` (branch arms `Some(b'(')` and then either `None if some_i32 == …` or `None => { match some_i32 { … } }`).
- Yet another would be to change the type from `i32` to your own enum, which is probably the cleanest option but might require some convincing of the Rust compiler to get an `i32`-like representation if you need that for some reason.
- Finally, you could define `const PAREN_OPEN: i32 = b'(' as i32;` and use `PAREN_OPEN` as the pattern.

Answer (score 3):

Since `as` expressions are allowed in constants, and matching is allowed against constants, you can use a constant:

```rust
const LPAREN: i32 = '(' as i32;
match v {
    LPAREN => { ... }
    // ...
}
```

If you can use nightly, you can use the `inline_const_pat` feature to reduce the boilerplate:

```rust
#![feature(inline_const_pat)]

match v {
    const { '(' as i32 } => { ... }
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way: here's a small proc macro that will replace the characters with their numerical value (it does not work with nested char patterns):

```rust
use proc_macro::TokenStream;

use quote::ToTokens;

#[proc_macro]
pub fn i32_match(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let mut input = syn::parse_macro_input!(input as syn::ExprMatch);
    for arm in &mut input.arms {
        if let syn::Pat::Lit(lit) = &mut arm.pat {
            if let syn::Expr::Lit(syn::ExprLit { lit, .. }) = &mut *lit.expr {
                if let syn::Lit::Char(ch) = lit {
                    *lit = syn::Lit::Int(syn::LitInt::new(
                        &(ch.value() as i32).to_string(),
                        ch.span(),
                    ));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    input.into_token_stream().into()
}
```

```rust
i32_match! {
    match v {
        '(' => { ... }
        // ...
    }
}
```